# What exactly does this "$this -> session -> userdata("datiPreventivo");" into a CodeIgniter controller class?

Tags: php, codeigniter, codeigniter-2

I am a Java developer (I often used Spring MVC to develop MVC web app in Java) with a very litle knowledge of PHP and I have to work on a PHP project that use **CodeIgniter 2.1.3**.

So I have the following doubt about how exactly work this controller method:

So I have this class:

```
class garanzieValoreFlex extends CI_Controller {

    ..................................................... 
    ..................................................... 
    ..................................................... 

   public function index() {

        $this->load->model('Direct');
        $flagDeroga = "true" ;

        $this->session->userdata("flagDeroga");

        $data = $this->session->userdata("datiPreventivo");
        $this->load->model('GaranzieValoreFlexModel');

        $data = $this->session->userdata("datiPreventivo");
        $this->load->model('GaranzieValoreFlexModel');

        $this->load->view('garanziavalore/index_bootstrap',$data);
    }

}
```

I know that the **index()** method of the **garanzieValoreFlex** controller class handle HTTP Request toward the URL: **http://MYURL/garanzieValoreFlex** and show the **/views/garanzievalore/index_bootstrap.php** page.

It works fine. The only think that I can't understand is what exactly does this code line:

```
$data = $this -> session -> userdata("datiPreventivo");
```

Can you help me what exactly is doing? I think that it is putting something into the HttpSession or something like this but I am absolutly not sure about it and I can't understand the logic.

Comment: https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/sessions.html

Comment: It retrieve the session data. Click to see the documentation http://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/sessions.html

Comment: If you have little knowledge of CodeIgniter, then reading the documentation would be a great idea.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`session` is a Codeigniter (CI) library (class) that allows data to persist across multiple page calls from a browser. In the version of CI you are using "native" PHP session functionality is not used. But CI's `session` class does mimic PHP's session in that data is stored in a PHP associative [array](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php).

The class has many different methods to store and retrieve user defined data. The function `userdata("index_to_data")` is one of the main class methods. It is used to retrieve data that has been stored in the `session` class.

The argument passed to `userdata()` is the key to a value in the `session` class array `$userdata`. So, `$this->session->userdata("datiPreventivo");` returns the value stored at `$userdata["datiPreventivo"]`. If the key (in this case "datiPreventivo") does not exist then `$this->session->userdata("datiPreventivo")` returns `FALSE`.

Somewhere in the code you are working with you will find a line where data is stored in the session. The line of code might look something like this.

```
$newdata = array("datiPreventivo" => $something_value);
$this->session->set_userdata($newdata);
```

Searching your code for "$this->session->set_userdata" might be helpful to understand what exactly is being saved for future page loads.

It is important to know that CI's `session` class was completely rewritten in versions > 3.0 so the [current documentation](http://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/sessions.html) may not be very helpful to you. You will need to find the documentation for the version you are using to learn more about the `session` library. I believe that documentation is included in the download for your version which can be found [here](http://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/installation/downloads.html).